# AWS CloudFormation: How to use Github Enterprise as Source in AWS Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-enterprise, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

In Documentation, we are given the following example:

```
AppPipeline: 
  Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline 
  Properties: 
    RoleArn:
      Ref: CodePipelineServiceRole 
    Stages: 
      - 
        Name: Source 
        Actions: 
          - 
            Name: SourceAction
            ActionTypeId: 
              Category: Source 
              Owner: AWS 
              Version: 1 
              Provider: S3 
            OutputArtifacts: 
              - 
                Name: SourceOutput 
            Configuration: 
              S3Bucket: 
                Ref: SourceS3Bucket 
              S3ObjectKey: 
                Ref: SourceS3ObjectKey 
            RunOrder: 1
```

I have tried to update it to use GitHub enterprise but unfortunately it doesn't work.
Can someone show how to correctly configure it.
This is how i tried to do that:

```
- Name: Source
  Actions:
    - Name: Source
      RunOrder: 1
      InputArtifacts: []
      ActionTypeId:
        Category: Source
        Owner: ThirdParty
        Provider: GitHubEnterpriseServer
      Configuration:
        Owner: !Sub ${GitHubRepositoryOwner}
        Repo: !Sub ${GitHubRepositoryName}
        Branch: !Sub ${GitHubIntegrationBranch}
        OAuthToken: !Sub ${GitHubPersonalAccessToken}
        PollForSourceChanges: false # Must be set to false when using webhooks
      OutputArtifacts:
        - Name: SourceArtifact
```

Update:

I found the Github Enterprise uses codestar-connections.
I have edit my code to look like this:

```
  Stages:
    - Name: Source
      Actions:
        - InputArtifacts: []
          ActionTypeId:
            Version: '1'
            Owner: AWS
            Category: Source
            Provider: CodeStarSourceConnection
          OutputArtifacts:
            - Name: SourceArtifact
          RunOrder: 1
          Configuration:
            ConnectionArn: "arn:aws:codestar-connections:exxxxxxxxf382816da8"
            FullRepositoryId: "https://github.xxxxxx/cloudformation"
            BranchName: "main"
            OutputArtifactFormat: "CODE_ZIP"
          Name: ApplicationSource
```

The problem that I am dealing now is a connection permission:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx is not authorized to perform: codestar-connections:PassConnection on resource:
```

Comment: Are you using Github enterprise cloud or server? If its cloud, instead of  `GitHubEnterpriseServer`  it should simply be `Provider: GitHub`

Comment: Hi @BaluVyamajala, i am using the Server.